# I accidentally charged more than the amount on a prepaid card on amazon and it didn't get declined

Tags: gift-card

So, I accidentally charged more than the amount on a prepaid visa debit gift card on an online retailer and it didn't get declined. What will happen? Should I take advantage of this?

Comment: "Should I take advantage of this?" sounds like you already did. Is the card reloadable?

Comment: Is the card associated with you in any way?

Comment: @TTT does it make it less illegal if it's not ?

Comment: @xyious - I ask because if the answer is no, then I question whether it's even possible. It could simply be an auth without a charge that was approved.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The card will not be charged until the order is prepared. Once Amazon attempts to charge the card, it will be declined. If there are no other payment options in your account the package will not be sent.

Comment: This makes sense. Let's hope OP can confirm this is indeed what happens, if/when it does.

Comment: I charged it with two items, 1 that already went through successfully (I think... (it was a digital purchase)) that used the card up entirely and another that is a shipment, so we will see.

Comment: It's likely the case that the timing and order of those two transactions is what allowed the authorizations to go through, but I don't think that changes Bob's answer (which I suspect will turn out to be true).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, in the "Your package is on the way!" email, they automatically switched to the default payment method, my credit card.

Comment: Mystery solved! Thanks for the update.